# Cut last folder from url/string with split and join

Tags: go, url, join, split, path

Is there any easier way in Go (an elegant one with the generic imports)
to combine URL parts and join them together without the last element, while not dissembling and putting it back together, but rather a smart cut ?

All I want is to get rid of the `/custom:*` form the image name(s)

```
URL := "gcr.io/google-containers/controller-manager-arm64/custom:v6.2"
sURL := strings.Split(URL, "/")
tURL := sURL[:len(sURL)-1]
endURL := strings.Join(tURL, "/")
fmt.Println("proper URL ", endURL)
```

Here's my
[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/lLCz5HSmsh-)

EDIT:
method `filepath.Split` leaves `/` at the end which i don't want to trim afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `path.Dir` function:

```
path.Dir(URL)
```

This will cut the last component from a path.